# GCC extension __attribute__ ((unused)) for variable attributes

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-extensions

following is a sample code for GCC variable attribute extension,

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void){
        int sam __attribute__((unused))= 10;
        int p = sam+1;
        printf("\n%d" , p);
}
```

for the assembly code of above program generated using:

```
gcc -S sample.c
```

the .s file dosen't contain the variable sam in it,whereas the output of program is "11" which is correct.
So does the compiler neglect completely the unused variable and not output it in the executable? If so why is the output of program correct?Can anyone explain the working of unused and used variable attributes in gcc.

Thanks

Comment: `__attribute__((unused))` merely influences what *warnings* the compiler will emit.  It makes no difference to code generation and optimisation.

Comment: Modern compilers are very smart when they optimize. The compiler can see that `sam + 1` equals `11` and can print it directly without using variables.

Answer (score 2):

> So does the compiler neglect completely the unused variable

Depends what you mean by "neglect". The compiler optimizes the code, but doesn't completely ignore the variable, as otherwise compiler couldn't calculate the result.

> not output it in the executable?

Yes.

> If so why is the output of program correct?

Because this is what a compiler does - generates programs with the output as described by the programming language. Code is not 1:1 to assembly, code is a language that describes the *behavior* of a program. Theoretically, as long as the *output* of the compiled program is correct with what is in the source code, compiler can generate any assembly instructions it wants.

You may want to research the terms *side effect* and the *as-if rule* in the context of C programming language.

> Can anyone explain the working of unused and used variable attributes in gcc.

There is no better explanation then in [GCC documentation about Variable Attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.2.0/gcc/Common-Variable-Attributes.html#Common-Variable-Attributes):

> unused
>
> > This attribute, attached to a variable, means that the variable is meant to be possibly unused. GCC does not produce a warning for this variable.
>
> used
>
> > This attribute, attached to a variable with static storage, means that the variable must be emitted even if it appears that the variable is not referenced.
> >
> > When applied to a static data member of a C++ class template, the attribute also means that the member is instantiated if the class itself is instantiated.

The attribute `unused` is to silence the compiler warning from `-Wunused-*` warnings.

The attribute `used` is meant to be used on variables (but I think works also on functions) so that the variable is generated to the assembly code. even if it is not unused anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

try compiling with no optimisation

```
gcc -O0 sample.c -S -masm=intel
```

generated assembly code

```
    .file   "sample.c"
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    .text
    .def    __main; .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .section .rdata,"dr"
.LC0:
    .ascii "\12%d\0"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .def    main;   .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .seh_proc   main
main:
    push    rbp
    .seh_pushreg    rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    .seh_setframe   rbp, 0
    sub rsp, 48
    .seh_stackalloc 48
    .seh_endprologue
    call    __main
    mov DWORD PTR -4[rbp], 10
    mov eax, DWORD PTR -4[rbp]
    add eax, 1
    mov DWORD PTR -8[rbp], eax
    mov eax, DWORD PTR -8[rbp]
    mov edx, eax
    lea rcx, .LC0[rip]
    call    printf
    mov eax, 0
    add rsp, 48
    pop rbp
    ret
    .seh_endproc
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 10.2.0"
    .def    printf; .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
```